# Dialogflow fails to parse Webhook response from Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, webhooks, dialogflow-es

I'm getting the following error when I try to pass a webhook response from Google Apps Script to Dialogflow. [Full debug log](https://hastebin.com/royeluzaxo.tex).

```
Webhook call failed. Error: Failed to parse webhook JSON response: 
Expect message object but got: \\\"<HTML>\\\
```

Here's an excerpt from my Google Apps Script.

```
function doPost(e) {
    var myData = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
    ...
    ...
    var replyJSON = ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(result)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    return replyJSON;
}
```

I've used Postman to check if my Google Apps script is returning a JSON (it is).

```
{
    "fulfillmentText": "Hello",
    "fulfillmentMessages": [{
        "text": {
            "text": [
                "Hello"
            ]
        }
    }],
}
```

I've followed the Dialogflow v2 API [documentation](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment#response) to properly format the response JSON.

I can't figure out what's wrong. I've no idea how it could be receiving a HTML file instead of a JSON. It shouldn't be this hard to create a custom webhook response, but the Dialogflow documentation is ***awful***.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
The Google Web App is published and able to be used anonymously.

Edit edit:
More [logs](https://hastebin.com/osisakagas.vbs) from Stackdriver.

Comment: Check permissions / availability of the webapp. You could be getting a 404 / 401 error page, calling the `/exec` version while only the `/dev` version is outputting json, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've tested the webapp with both `/dev` and `/exec` using Postman. I've also made sure the Web App is published and able to be used anonymously. No dice.

Comment: That debugging was coming from the Actions on Google Simulator? You may also want to turn on "Log interactions to Google Cloud" - you can get to it from the settings (clicking on the Gear icon) and scrolling down and adding some of the expanded log entries to your question.

Comment: Hi Prisoner, I recognise your username from around here. I've included all the logs from the project, and I realised that the response from Google Apps is a redirect link to another URL! Do you know if there's anyway for Dialogflow to recognise this redirect?

Comment: I don't see evidence of the redirect in the question. The stackdriver logs usually provide what, exactly, came back from your webhook, so I'm a little confused. However, I don't believe that Dialogflow can handle a redirect for security purposes.

Comment: @yeowx Try publishing a new version of the web app. For some reason updating an existing version doesn't always work (its a known issue with GAS web apps).

Comment: @Prisoner Hey! I met you at a GDG event (Bronx, NY) last year. Glad to see that you frequent these parts.

Comment: @Prisoner In the hastebin link on line 15 where the Fulfillment response is. That looks to me like the response that the GAS is returning to Dialogflow. Hmmm okay I'll try and find another way around this.

Comment: @Dimu Hey, thanks for your input! I've already noticed that quirk in GAS, and I'm up to version 80 now. :( I believe my problem is that Dialogflow can't follow the HTTP redirect that's returned by GAS, so the Agent just flops about.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a redirect issue. Maybe your JSON is malformed after you process it (the lines you omitted). Try testing the doPost as an echo to see if it works:

```
function doPost(e) {
      var content = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);

      return ContentService
              .createTextOutput()
              .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
              .setContent(JSON.stringify(content));
}
```

Comment: I've tried it out with just your code, but Dialogflow is still getting the same HTML response. [Logs](https://hastebin.com/yoqolufate.js). I remember reading about this redirect thing somewhere else, but I can't seem to find the link. IIRC the main gist of it was that Dialogflow can't follow the HTTP redirect request. Which explains why Postman receives the JSON response just fine while Dialogflow craps the bed. Thanks for your suggestion, at least now I'm pretty certain why this is happening. :D

Comment: @yeowx Do you have a paid gsuite account? You could try implementing this using a cloud function instead of a GAS web app.

Comment: I don't have a paid account, but I can try poking around. I wonder if Dialogflow is considered a "Google API"

Comment: @yeowx There is a REST API for DialogFlow...Check this out: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ContentService` from Google Apps Script. `ContentService` provides the response through a temporary redirect.
DialogFlow does not follow the redirect hence it gets the `302/303` page which is an intermediary html page that is why you see the JSON parse error.
I hosted a webinar to address this issue many years ago and recommended a probable solution ( a web proxy ). May be it will help you. Here is the link to the webinar.

- https://tu.appsscript.info/previous-episodes/season-1/tu11